# "pipenv install" in empty directory doesn't create a Pipfile, but uses a Pipfile.lock from somewhere else

Tags: pipenv, pipenv-install

I ran `pipenv install` to create a `Pipfile` in the current directory that doesn't have a `Pipfile`.  It gave the following output but did not create a `Pipfile`.  Why not?

```
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (639627)…
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
```

It looks like it found a `Pipfile.lock` somewhere and used it? (similar to `git` behavior)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `PIPENV_NO_INHERIT` environment variable to ignore inheriting from directories above the current directory, e.g.,

```
PIPENV_NO_INHERIT=True pipenv install
```

In your case, `pipenv` searched directories above the current directory and found a Pipfile there that it used (the location of which can be seen with `pipenv --where`).

(Incidently, I looked at the `pipenv` documentation but was unable to find where it discussed this behavior, so please add a link here to that documentation if you find it.)

Comment: https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#pipenv.environments.PIPENV_NO_INHERIT

Answer (score 0):

I ran pipenv shell first (creat Pipfile), then pipenv install (creat Pipfile.lock)

'pip install pipenv' command returns "Requirement already satisfied ..."